# C++ Copy constructor and stl map

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor

I have an Actor class that has map _abilities

The Actor class has a copy constructor and inside this I want to copy the abilities in this map to the new actor instance. Ability also has a copy constructor.

So my plan was to loop over the ability map for the passed in actor instance I'm copying from and create new abilities. I do this because each ability actually acts and modifies the actor so when I copy an actor I need new instances of all it's abilities as well. The following code gives me an error in the for loop when it's trying to assign the passed in actor abilities to the iter:

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type     'std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,Ability     *,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,Ability *>>,false>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(429): could be 'std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree> &std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree>::operator =(const std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,Ability *,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,Ability *>>,false>>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree>, std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<std::string,Ability *,std::less<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,Ability *>>,false>>
1>          ]

// _abilities define as
map<string, Ability*> _abilities;

Actor::Actor(const Actor& actor)
{
// make a copy of this actors model and stats
_model = CopyEntity(actor._model);
_stats = actor._stats;

// copy the abilities and assign this as the new actor
map<string, Ability*>::iterator iter;
for(iter = actor._abilities.begin(); iter != actor._abilities.end(); ++iter)
    _abilities[(*iter).first] = new Ability(*(*iter).second, this);
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't let me do this. The types match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`actor` is a const object. So `actor._abilities.begin()` would return `const_iterator`, not `iterator`.

Try this:

```
map<string, Ability*>::const_iterator iter;
```

instead of this:

```
map<string, Ability*>::iterator iter;
```

In C++11, you can use `auto` which takes care of const-correctness also:

```
for(auto iter = actor._abilities.begin(); /* same as before */)
      _abilities[iter->first] = new Ability(*(iter->second), this);
}
```

Hope that helps.